# how to use linux's network namespace feature to measure the bytes sent/received over network by a process?

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, nic, linux-namespaces

I have this situation where I need to measure the bytes sent/received during its execution. The PC will have a normal ethernet interface (eth1) to interact with others in the network. I did a little research on linux network namespace and cgroups, given that, I came to this approach to do the measures.

- create a new network namespace.
- create a virtual ethernet pair of interfaces veth0 and veth1.
- assign veth1 to the previously created namespace leaving veth0 on the default namespace.
- configure the virtual interfaces and create a bridge between veth0 and eth1.

Given that, I will execute my process on the new namespace and assume the values from veth1 as the bytes sent/received for the process. I know that I can use iproute2 and bridge-utils for the above steps, but is it correct? or there is another way to do that kind of measure?

Comment: Assuming that your application is operating over a unique set of ports, you can simply create `iptables` firewall rules that match those ports and use the byte/packet counts that are maintained automatically by the kernel.

Comment: Yes, that seems promising. More specifically, I need to measure a java process with two independent NIO servers: an udp server on port 9900 and a tcp server on port 9901. How can I do the measure using iptables?